# How to filter a determined quantity of rows in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I'm trying to obtain a specific result using the `HAVING` statement in a MySQL query. Let's me explain better:

I have the follow table structure +data:

```
| ID | COLUMN1| COLUMN2|
|----|--------|--------|
|1   |   52   | APPLE  |
|2   |   52   | APPLE  |
|3   |   58   | ORANGE |
|4   |   58   | ORANGE |
|5   |   61   | ORANGE |
|6   |   50   | ORANGE |
|7   |   50   | ORANGE |
|8   |   58   | LEMON  |
|9   |   58   | LEMON  |
|10  |   53   | LEMON  |
|11  |   53   | LEMON  |
```

When I submit this query:

```
select column1, column2, count(column2)
    from new_table     
    group by column1, column2      
    having count(column2) > 1
    order by column2;
```

result this:

```
'52', 'APPLE', '2'
'53', 'LEMON', '2'
'58', 'LEMON', '2'
'50', 'ORANGE', '2'
'58', 'ORANGE', '2'
```

But, at really, I want to hide all the result that appears in only one colum1, therefore, I want to hide the 'APPLE' line, because the two occurrence are from the same Column1 (52). I'd like the following result:

```
'53', 'LEMON', '2'
'58', 'LEMON', '2'
'50', 'ORANGE', '2'
'61', 'ORANGE', '1'
'58', 'ORANGE', '2'
```

Comment: "I want to hide the 'APPLE' line, because the two occurrence are from the same Column1 (52)" But the same is happening for all others.. Can you please explain again what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I need to hide all the fruits that does not appear in at least two rows with different value in colum1

Comment: ok, it is worded weird, as ORANGE 58 shows up in your desired results

Comment: ORANGE shows up in my result because it is appears in more than one different column1. APPLE is the only fruit that appear in only one column1, therefore I'd like to hide it.

Comment: Add a `WHERE Column2 <> 'APPLE'`

Comment: Leptonator, it's only a example. In a real world I dont will know previously what's the data nor how many fruits I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT column2
FROM new_table          
GROUP BY column2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column1) > 1
```

to get `column2` values that correlate to *more than one* `column1` values.

If you incorporate the above in your query you get:

```
SELECT column1, column2, count(column2) AS cnt
FROM new_table          
WHERE column2 IN (SELECT column2
                  FROM new_table          
                  GROUP BY column2
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column1) > 1)
GROUP BY column1, column2      
ORDER BY column2;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bc4e/2)

Comment: But with this query, the row 61/ORANGE does not shows up... I'd like to obtain all the fruits that appear in more than one column1 and hide all fruits than appear in only one column1 (in this case, the only row would be APPLE/52)

Comment: @dellasavia In that case just leave the `HAVING` clause out of the query. Sorry, I misinterpreted your requirements.

Comment: You are the one! More a time you helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to select fruits for which a record with another value exists, so use `WHERE EXISTS`. Then aggregate to get one result row per fruit with the record count.

```
select column1, column2, count(*)
from new_table
where exists
(
  select *
  from new_table other
  where other.column2 = new_table.column2
  and other.column1 <> new_table.column1
)
group by column1, column2;
```